# Prove $\varepsilon X$ and $\varepsilon |X|$ have the same distribution for $\varepsilon$ symmetric Bernoulli (Exercise 6.4.1 (a) of HDP book)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was studying the High-Dimensional Probability book by Roman Vershynin and asked to "check that $\varepsilon X$ and $\varepsilon |X|$ are symmetric random variables, and they have the same distribution", where $X$ can be any random variable and $\varepsilon $ is an independent symmetric Bernoulli random variable. The first part of the statement is simple, but I have difficulty in showing they equal in distribution. My attemp was as follows.

> We can write $\varepsilon X=\varepsilon \operatorname{sign}(X)|X|$, and we have $\varepsilon \operatorname{sign}(X)$ equals $\varepsilon $ in distribution and then get the conclusion. However, I then realized that, this strategy is infeasible as $\varepsilon \operatorname{sign}(X)$ and $|X|$ are not independent. (For a simple example that this is infeasible without independence, consider two i.i.d. random variables $Y$ and $Z$. We see $Z$ equals $Y$ in distribution by definition, but it does not hold that $Y^2$ and $ZY$ equal in distribution as $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)\neq\mathbb{E}(ZY)$ where the latter equals $\mathbb{E}(Z)\mathbb{E}(Y)=(\mathbb{E}(Y))^2$ by independence.)

I don't know how to prove this fact.

Comment: Can you express their CDFs via the CDF of $X$?

Comment: Conditional distrbutions given $X$ are the same. Now take expectation.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for your comment. Conditioning on $X$, we have $\mathbb{E}_\varepsilon(\varepsilon X\vert X)=\mathbb{E}_\varepsilon(\varepsilon |X|\vert X)=0$. But I don't know how to proceed to show the fact. I am sorry but I am wondering if I have correctly understood what you mean.

Comment: @Ilya Yes. By the law of total probability, I can write $\mathbb{P}(\varepsilon X\le t)=\frac{1+\mathbb{P}(X\le t)-\mathbb{P}(X\le -t)}{2}$. Similarly but with some discussions on the sign of $t$, I can show $\mathbb{P}(\varepsilon |X|\le t)=\frac{1+\mathbb{P}(X\le t)-\mathbb{P}(X\le -t)}{2}$ as well. Therefore, they are equal in distribution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Characteristic function](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory))

$$\varphi_{\varepsilon X}(t) = \mathbb E\left[e^{it\varepsilon X}\right] = \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[e^{it\varepsilon X}\Big | X\right]\right] = \frac12\left(\varphi_X(t) + \varphi_X(-t)\right) = \varphi_{\varepsilon \left|X\right|}(t)$$

Comment: Excellent idea! Thanks for your answer.